# change bool with StateMachineBehaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, boolean

I have a bool in my character's script that I want not to be active in certain animation states of my animator controller.
To do this I know that you have to create a script with StateMachineBehaviour to attach to the animation state, but how do I call a State bool that is on a MonoBehaviour script in that same object with StateMachineBehaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the MonoBehaviour component that you wish to reference is attached to the same game object as the Animator component that you have assigned your StateMachineBehaviour to, you can get a reference using:

```
var component = animator.GetComponent<YourComponent>();
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    var component = animator.GetComponent<YourComponent>();
    component.valueToChange = true;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what if I want to disable the movement ..? canceling the rotation however the character rotates differently from how it should rotate because my vector of movement (transform.forward) remains active and while rotating however the character goes in that direction.
If I disable it as the rotation, the character no longer moves because Controller.Move uses this vector to move.
How can I do so as not to interfere with the root movement of the character..???

Comment: This seems like a different problem to your original question